# Find the closest minimum timestamp (from a array of dictionaries) to a given timestamp

Tags: python, date, dictionary

Having the following list of dictionaries, which includes a timestamp (in string value) and a value:

```
    my_example = [{'timestamp': '2009-11-10T23:00:01Z', 'value': 1},
                  {'timestamp': '2009-11-10T23:00:05Z', 'value': 2}, 
                  {'timestamp': '2009-11-10T23:00:20Z', 'value': 3}]
```

I want for a given timestamp value (in string format), find the the (closest) minimum value. It's a bit messy for me to explain, so it's better to see it on an example:

- If the given_timestamp is `2009-11-10T23:00:019Z` I want to return:  `{'timestamp': '2009-11-10T23:00:05Z', 'value': 2}` (and not `{'timestamp': '2009-11-10T23:00:20Z', 'value': 3}`).
- If the given_timestamp is `2009-11-10T23:00:04Z` I want to return:  `{'timestamp': '2009-11-10T23:00:01Z', 'value': 1}` (and not `{'timestamp': '2009-11-10T23:00:05Z', 'value': 2}`).
- If the given_timestamp is `2009-11-10T23:00:05Z` I want to return:  `{'timestamp': '2009-11-10T23:00:05Z', 'value': 2}`.

The following code gets the closest value, but I dont know how to modify it to get the minimum value.

```
import datetime
my_example = [{'timestamp': '2009-11-10T23:00:01Z', 'value': 1}, {'timestamp': '2009-11-10T23:00:05Z', 'value': 2}, {'timestamp': '2009-11-10T23:00:20Z', 'value': 3}]
myNumber = "2009-11-10T23:00:19Z"
myNumber = datetime.datetime.strptime(myNumber, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
res = min(my_example, key=lambda x:abs(datetime.datetime.strptime(x["timestamp"], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ") - myNumber))
print(res)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `res` just gave you the closest `timestamp` dict. You want `res['timestamp`]  or `res['value']` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to tuples, replace the future dates with infinity and then take the min.

*Your data:*

```
import datetime
my_example = [{'timestamp': '2009-11-10T23:00:01Z', 'value': 1}, {'timestamp': '2009-11-10T23:00:05Z', 'value': 2}, {'timestamp': '2009-11-10T23:00:20Z', 'value': 3}]
myNumber = "2009-11-10T23:00:19Z"
myNumber = datetime.datetime.strptime(myNumber, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
res = min(my_example, key=lambda x:abs(datetime.datetime.strptime(x["timestamp"], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ") - myNumber))
print(res)
```

**Edit:** I changed it from pandas to datetime, and added in tuples. Here we take the day and second tuple of the list. We do some cluegy manipulation here to change everything that is in the future to infinity so we skip it. And then we just take the minimum of the tuple list which should return the closest time that is not in the future.

```
def get_min_time(myNumber, list_):
    myNumber = datetime.datetime.strptime(myNumber, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
    times = [(myNumber - datetime.datetime.strptime(x["timestamp"], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")) for x in list_]
    tups = [(x.days, x.seconds) for x in times]
    tups = [(float("inf"), float("inf")) if time < (0, 0) else time for time in tups]
    return list_[tups.index(min(tups))]



get_min_time("2009-11-10T23:00:19Z", my_example)
{'timestamp': '2009-11-10T23:00:05Z', 'value': 2}

get_min_time("2009-11-10T23:00:04Z", my_example)
{'timestamp': '2009-11-10T23:00:01Z', 'value': 1}

get_min_time("2009-11-10T23:00:05Z", my_example)
{'timestamp': '2009-11-10T23:00:05Z', 'value': 2}
```

If you need to run this against a whole list of things just use list comprehension:

```
[get_min_time(x, list_) for x in my_Numbers]
```

Comment: Hi, Matt, Thanks for the reply. This fails when if `myNumber` is a timestamp already included on the list. `myNumber = "2009-11-10T23:00:5Z"` returns `{'timestamp': '2009-11-10T23:00:01Z', 'value': 1}` instead of `{'timestamp': '2009-11-10T23:00:05Z', 'value': 2}`. (PS: I can't use Pandas and I edited the post to clarify it a bit).

Comment: how come you can't use pandas? can you use numpy?

Comment: edited it to fit. its a bit cluegy but should work. If you need it to span years, or go down to microseconds, you can add that in the tups section for (x.years, x.days, x.seconds) and then change the list comprehension to time < (0, 0, 0)

Comment: Hi, Matt, thakns a lot! I can't use pandas or numpy as they are libraries not included with the original python installation, and for several reasons I can't install them. The solution works but I need to span years. Tried with `(x.years, x.days, x.seconds)` but I get `AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'years'`

Comment: yeah I misread that. it doesn't have a years attribute. But days go to infinity it seems. So just keep it as `(x.days, x.seconds)`. That will be able to span years.
And you should look into getting anaconda. But anyways - this solution will work